# Pass Jenkins Build When Gradle Step Fails

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins

I have a project setup in Jenkins that uses gradle to build.  I have setup the build to happen in multiple steps, the first is the build, the second actually deploys the WAR to the tomcat server.  The issue being, if the WAR fails to deploy for some reason, the whole build fails.  Is there a way to pass the build when certain steps fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... Assuming your talking about https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin. 
You should be separating your build and deploy tasks into different jenkins jobs, for many reasons, this being one of them.

At the end of your build job archive the artifacts. 
Use the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin to Move your war file to the deploy Jobs workspace, and then deploy. If the deployment fails, you do not have to rebuild the application for no reason.

Comment: Thank you.  I was using gradle to do the deployment.  It makes a lot more sense to use this deploy plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd still like to do the deployment with Gradle you could take a look at the Clone Workspace plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin

A much richer explanation on how-to is shared on these nice slides from Benjamin Muschko https://speakerdeck.com/bmuschko/building-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-with-gradle-and-jenkins